# Setting the loudspeaker on from service does not give desired result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-audiomanager

I am trying to call a particular number from my service in my app. I can successfully do that using the below code.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)  
                                  getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);                 

audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Then  I called up my number using the below code,

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "1234"));
callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

However sometimes it does not set the loudspeaker on.

I have appropriate permission on my manifest that is

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

I learned from somewhere that I need to add 
`setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);`
which is of Activity however as I am at my service and I don not want to open my activity how would I able to do my task effectively.

Answer (score 0):

What I have been missing I think is the context like I have been calling the AudioManager services from my service which is not working in stead of that I tried to call these service from a broadcast receiver which listens to action.PHONE_STATE. So when ever I try to dial a number the state of Telephony Manager changes to EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK then I change to audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true) and this seems to work for every call.

Thanks all!!!